# SQLite3 multithread at same server

Tags: php, multithreading, sqlite, wal

How can I perform a SQLite3 exec at the same time in PHP?
I have this code (by example):

```
$bd = new SQLite3("database.db");
$bd->busyTimeout(5000);
$bd->exec("INSERT into 'foo' ('data') values ('bar')");
$bd->close();
unset($bd);
```

And it works, but the real problem is when I connect another computer to my server and I made the insert at the same time (really, I press the key that trigger the code at the same time in both computers) and it show an error "database is locked".

I know that with the pragma WAL the database works in multithread, but it even show the error. Thank you a lot! and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `sqlite3` employs database locking, as opposed to row or column locking like `mysql` or `postgresql`.  If you want to do two things at the same time try using [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/get_started.html), or [postgresql](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Detailed_installation_guides).  In `mysql` you would have to [create the database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-database.html).  Your code would then look something like this:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

$count = $conn->exec("INSERT into 'foo' ('data') values ('bar')");
$conn = null // close connection
```

Comment: And if I use MongoDB?

Comment: MongoDB would be fine.  The query about is an ```SQL``` query though so I assumed you wanted to stick with ```mysql```.  ```mongodb``` is awesome to though. There's php mongo db documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php